# css selector "#id.classname" vs "#id .classname"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have realized that the css selector

```
"#id.classname"
```

vs

```
"#id .classname"
```

is not the same. See the whitespace in the 2nd sample.

What is the difference between those two?

I thought both mean a class applied to an element with that id.

Comment: so many identical questions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whitespace makes a huge difference because it is the [descendant selector combinator](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/descendant).

The first selector applies to an element with id `id` that has the class `classname`.

The second applies to an element that has the class `classname` which is also a descendant of the element with id `id`.